# Get notified when an NFC card is in range

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, nfc, uwp

How do I get notified when an arbitrary NFC card (any card with a chip) is in range of my Windows mobile phone? I have a Lumia 640 which has NFC capabilities.

Unfortunately, I've only found how to subscribe to a specific type of card using [ProximityDevice.SubscribeForMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.subscribeformessage) which needs a `messageType`. I want a generic card reader. How do I do that?

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain why? Perhaps it's simple for you. But I don't know how it's done, and I've been searching the web not finding anything.

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?  Any code that you've worked on. The link you put in makes sense as a starting point. Did you try that code and failed to modify it for a larger range of messages? if so where is it failing?

Comment: @Peter4499 There is nothing to modify. The method is not overloaded, and I don't want a "range" of message types. I want all trillions of them. I want to receive something like `an NFC tag with messageType ABC is in range` in some event handler. This is what happens from a hardware point of view anyway. I just don't want Windows to ignore message types. I want to be informed that whatever messageType is within range, is within range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Proximity API only supports NDEF formatted tags. Thus it's not possible to detect "any card with chip". The closest you can get to that is to subscribe to any tag that contains a valid NDEF message (this essentially boils down to "any tag supported by the device"):

```
subscribedMessageId = proximityDevice.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", messageReceived);
```

where `proximityDevice` is your instance of the `ProximityDevice` and `messageReceived` is the `MessageReceivedHandler`.

Note that there also is the [Smartcard API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.smartcards.smartcardreader.aspx) which can be used to enumerate and access certain contactless smartcards through the NFC reader.